# How to fix 「ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow」 when using devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, devise

### Want to achieve

Ruby 2.6.5
Ruby on Rails 6.0.3

Thankyou for visiting!
I am creating an application in Ruby on Rails.
I am also using devise to build the login relationship.

Suddenly, the following error occurred:

```
ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow (ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow)
```

The error message said there were too many cookies, so I looked at the contents of session.

```
session.to_hash
=> {"session_id"=>"4ceff7435d264fb8f7b41bacb8f2ba06",
 "_csrf_token"=>"zrbECxocvrrdIRD85hABDE18kRwiIttAP2B3hvbkeuk=",
 "warden.user.user.key"=>
  #<User id: 160, email: "sbxtestmike+latest3@gmail.com", last_name: "test_lastname", first_name: "test_firstname", profile: "In the event that you're looking for the best way to get the most out of your business, you'll be able to get the most..."}
```

It seems that this error occurs when there is a lot of data in the user profile. So I would like to avoid storing only the profile in the session.

I have no idea where to fix this.
If you could just give me some hints or ideas, I'd be happy to hear them.

Here is the code where I thought it was relevant.

```
    def verify
      prms = verify_params

        logger.debug 'success'
        sign_in(:user, @user)

        @resource = @user
        @resource.tokens = nil
        @token = @resource.create_token
        @resource.save!

        auth_header = @resource.build_auth_header(@token.token, @token.client)
        response.headers.merge!(auth_header)

      end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

First of in what directory are there too many cookies?

Why don't you check for cookies first and then CRUD.

Consider the combinations of hashes and symbols to make your data more concise but still practical.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).